# Linphone iphone build

Tags: ios, xcode, linphone, linphone-sdk

I'm trying to build linphone iPhone, I've followed the guide here https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone
I have cocoapods 1.8.4
Then run pod install in the project directory and everything works fine
Then open linphone.xcworkspace file
But, I got the error `No such module 'linphone'` when trying to build it.
[This is the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEHQr.png)
So, please any help?

Comment: anyone could help?

Answer (score 1):

try again. I got one step further. everything in Xcode. But I have trouble adapting it to my credentials.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).